# Iterating through words in a string using split()

Tags: python, while-loop, split

I am trying to match address `x` with address `y` using a `while` loop and `split()` to iterate through the words in the string, removing one at a time until a match is found. I am showing a `type error`

I am wondering if someone can help me with the how to cycle through the words using this process propererly?

```
x = 'Shop  9 Corner Cramer and Mary Street, Preston'
y = 'Corner Cramer and Mary Street, Preston'

def cut2(address):
    while address != y:
        p = address.split((" ",0)[0])
        p = p + 1
        
        print(f"Address Check {address}")
              
    else:
        print(address)
```

The output I want is:
`Corner Cramer and Mary Street, Preston`

The output I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a8e028e05091> in <module>
----> 1 cut2(x)

<ipython-input-3-342a77a7d0bd> in cut2(address)
      5     while address != y:
      6         p = address.split((" ",0)[0])
----> 7         p = p + 1
      8 
      9         print(f"Address Check {address}")

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Comment: `split` strings into `list`s of words, make `set`s from the `list`s and do set intersection

Comment: `while address != y` - how do you think this condition can become false? Both `address` and `y` never change.

Comment: How are the commas treated? as part of words, or should not be taken into account? (should be clear from the expected output required by @TrentonMcKinney)

Comment: @mkrieger1 my understanding (very new still) is that the ``while address`` checks the parameter against the ``y`` variable and then will do the splitting process until it does work? Would an ``if`` or ``elif`` be more appropriate?

Comment: `while address` checks the parameter against the `y` variable - but inside `while` you don't change `address` nor `y` so it will comapre again the same `address` and `y` and it will repeat code (which doesn't change `address` nor `y`) and run it again, and again - this loop will never stop.

Comment: better see `print(p)` becuse it has different value then you expect - it has `Shop` from `address` and in `p = p + 1` you try to do `p = "Shop" + 1`. `split` doesn't change `address` content . You should rather use `word, address = address.split(" ", 1)`

Comment: Thank you for your response @furas, my thinking was to make the code split the string, removing one word at a time, until it found a match the ``+=1`` was my attempt to iterate through the ``max split`` and ``index position`` (" ", 0)[0] -> (" ", 1)[1] etc. So that would have been the change in the ``while`` loop - in theory at least. 

What do you mean by ``word, address``... ?

Comment: see `print(address.split(" ", 1))` and you should see list `['Shop', ' 9 Corner Cramer and Mary Street, Preston']` and when you do `word, address = ['Shop', ' 9 Corner Cramer and Mary Street, Preston']` then you get `word = 'Shop'` and `address = 9 Corner Cramer and Mary Street, Preston'` - so you get new address without first word.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `print(p)` in

```
x = 'Shop  9 Corner Cramer and Mary Street, Preston'
p = x.split((" ",0)[0])
print(p)
```

then you see

```
['']
```

so late you try to do

```
p = [''] + 1
```

and this gives you error

---

It should be rather something like

```
def cut2(address, match):
    count = 0
    # firt check if `address` is not empty  
    while address and address != match:
        parts = address.split(" ", 1)
        word = parts[0]
        if len(parts) > 1:
            address = parts[1]
        else:
            address = ''
        count += 1
        print(f"Address Check: {address}")
        
    if address:        
        print(f'Found after {count} step(s) | {address}')
    else:
        print('Not found')

# --- main ---

y = 'Corner Cramer and Mary Street, Preston'

x = 'Shop  9 Corner Cramer and Mary Street, Preston'
cut2(x, y)

x = 'Hello World'
cut2(x, y)

x = ''
cut2(x, y)
```